# PyQt children widgets

Tags: python, pyqt

I have vertical layout (payment_dateLayout) and some line edit inside. Is there a way to get around all the line edits in the loop and get their name?

```
self.payment_dateLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused as to why there seem to be two nested vertical layouts (self.verticalLayoutWidget_7 is placed inside QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()), so I'll just assume that self.verticalLayoutWidget_7 is the one containing the line edits.

You can loop through the elements of a layout by using its [itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLayout.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.itemAt) method and iterating over the number of children ([count()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLayout.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.count)):

```
names = []
for i_widget in range(self.verticalLayoutWidget_7.count()):
    child = self.verticalLayoutWidget_7.itemAt(i_widget).widget()
    names.append(child.objectName())
print(names)
```